# Append X amount of results from one query to X amount of results from another (with no foreign key join)

Tags: sql, postgresql

This query brings back results like this: `select distinct date from dwh.product_count`

```
April, 2013
March, 2013
February, 2013
January, 2013
```

I'd like to append however many results ^that^ brings back to the results from this query:

`select distinct p_id dwh.members a`

```
5
7
8
...etc
```

So that my results would look like this:

```
5    April, 2013
5    March, 2013
5    February, 2013
5    January, 2013
7    April, 2013
7    March, 2013
7    February, 2013
7    January, 2013
etc....
```

What type of query would bring these results?

Comment: called a cross join - just select from both tables without any join conditions

Comment: @Randy I'm not sure how to do that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select id, dt
from 
    (select distinct p_id as id from dwh.members) s
    cross join
    (select distinct date as dt from dwh.product_count) t
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select id, dt from 
( select distinct p_id as id from dwh.members )
.( select distinct date as dt from dwh.product_count )
```

Comment: I'm getting this error: ERROR: ERROR: subquery in FROM must have an alias
  Hint: For
example, FROM (SELECT ...) [AS] foo.